# Add link with order data to Woocommerce email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a link that I need to add to the Woocommerce customer-processing email.
The link needs to have some order data base-encoded. The example of how the code needs to look like is

```
https://www.customlink.html&buyerEmail=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($buyerEmail));?>&shopOrderID=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($shopOrderID));?>
```

I tried to make this work for Woocommerce with this

```
echo "<a href="https://www.customlink.html&buyerEmail=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($order->billing_email;));?>&shopOrderID=<?php echo urlencode(base64_encode($order->get_order_number();));?>">Link</a>";
```

but I am getting errors wen trying to place an order. How do I need to change the code?